# Check if tensor is in list

Tags: python, pytorch, tensor

I can do the following with a single int to retrieve a bool tensor:

```py
import torch
a = torch.tensor([1,2,3])
a != 2
#tensor([ True, False,  True])
```

Can I do the same with a list in plain pytorch? I.e.:

```py
import torch
a = torch.tensor([1,2,3])
a not in [2,3]
#tensor([ True, False,  False])
```

Thanks a lot for your time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want [`torch.isin`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.isin.html)

```py
out = ~torch.isin(a, torch.tensor([2, 3]))
# or
out = torch.isin(a, torch.tensor([2, 3]), invert=True)
```

```
print(out)

tensor([ True, False, False])
```